# How would I return the minimum number of bits required to represent a number in two's complement?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Using only the following bitwise ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

```
int binarySize(int x) {
} 
return ?;
```

Comment: Are you just dumping all your homework here?

Comment: It is a homework question that the person should answer

Answer (score 5):

It seems like homeworks.

I start with some help. Place the return statement within the function brackets.

```
int binarySize(int x) {
    return ?;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering why it wasn't working